# CatBoostError: catboost/private/libs/target/target_converter.cpp:228: Unknown class label: "197"

Tags: machine-learning, catboost, catboostregressor

I am a trying to fit a catboost model to my data

```
#creating the model
model_cb = CatBoostClassifier(task_type='GPU', iterations=100, random_state=2020,eval_metric='F1')
#fitting the dataset into the model
model_cb.fit(X_train, y_train, cat_features= object_cols, plot=True,eval_set=(X_valid, y_valid))
```

but when I run the code I get error

```
CatBoostError: catboost/private/libs/target/target_converter.cpp:228: Unknown class label: "676"
```

Point me to the documentation to understand the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the documentation https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/about.html

CatBoostClassifier (a binary classifier) expects y_train to contain floats rather than strings.

Please note that as we do not monitor stackoverflow very closely, it is better to ask questions at github.com/catboost/catboost

Comment: The link is not currently accessible